# inter fragment communication onclick textview is null but in oncreate view textview is there

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

> Hi there, I try to sent data from one fragment to another fragment by implementing an interface. The interface Communicator implements two functions one of them is sendToBill(itemType, itemPrice). When the add button is clicked in the in the CategoryFragment class i want the the price of the item to be added to the amount in the footer fragment. The error i get when i click the add button is that the textview in the footer fragment is null.
>   In the FooterFragment class is a function updateBill(). When this function is called from onActivityCreated (within the footerFragment class) the view exist.

FooterBillFragment:

```
BillFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    private TextView totalAmount, text;
    private View mView;

    public FooterBillFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_footer_bill, container, false);
        return mView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        totalAmount = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.footer_display_amount);
        text = getView().findViewById(R.id.footer_bill_text);
        Log.d("ItemPrice", "item View footer " + text.getText().toString());
    }

    public void testTest() {
        totalAmount.setText("dit werkt wel");
    }

    public void updateFooterAmount(String itemPrice) {
        Log.d("ItemPrice", "item price footer " + itemPrice);
        totalAmount.setText("On click in CategorieFragment this TextView does 
        not exist"); This is where the error occurs
    }
}
```

My Activity:

```
public class IntermediateActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Communicator {

    private static int count = 0;
    private DatabaseReference mMenuCardDatabase;
    private FirebaseUser mCurrentUser;

    private ViewPager mPager;
    private MyFragmentPageAdapter mPageAdapter;
    private TabLayout mTabLayout;

    private ArrayList<String> categories;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_intermediate);

        categories = new ArrayList<>();
        String shop_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("shop_id");

        mCurrentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        mMenuCardDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("MenuCard").child(shop_id);
        mMenuCardDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    categories.add(ds.getKey().toString());
                }
                List<Fragment> fragments = buildFragments(categories.size());
                mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.intermediate_tabPager);

                mPageAdapter = new MyFragmentPageAdapter(IntermediateActivity.this, getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments, categories);
                mPager.setAdapter(mPageAdapter);
                mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.intermediate_tabs);

                mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mPager);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    public String getUserId() {
        String user_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("user_id");

        return user_id;
    }

    private List<android.support.v4.app.Fragment> buildFragments(int categoriesSize) {
        List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        for(int i = 0; i < categoriesSize; i++) {
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("position", i);
            String categorie = categories.get(i);

            b.putString("categorie", categorie);
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, CategoryFragment.class.getName() , b));
        }

        return fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public void respond(String shopType) {

    }

    @Override
    public void sendToBill(String itemName, String itemPrice) {
        count++;
        FooterBillFragment footerBillFragment = new FooterBillFragment();

        BillFragment billFragment = new BillFragment();
        billFragment.updateBill(itemName, itemPrice);

        Log.d("ItemPrice", "item price inter " + itemPrice);
        footerBillFragment.updateFooterAmount(itemPrice);
    }
}
```

CategoryFragment:

```
public class CategoryFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    private DatabaseReference mMenuCardDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;
    private FirebaseUser mCurrentUser;

    private RecyclerView mItemsList;
    private Communicator comm;


    public CategoryFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container, false);

        String categorie = this.getArguments().getString("categorie");


        mItemsList = (RecyclerView) mView.findViewById(R.id.items_guests_list);

        mItemsList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        mCurrentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(mCurrentUser.getUid());
        mMenuCardDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("MenuCard").child(mCurrentUser.getUid()).child(categorie);

        return mView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Items, ItemsViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Items, CategoryFragment.ItemsViewHolder>(
                Items.class,
                R.layout.single_menu_display_layout,
                ItemsViewHolder.class,
                mMenuCardDatabase
        ) {
   @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(CategoryFragment.ItemsViewHolder 
           viewHolder, Items item, int position) {

                comm = (Communicator) getActivity();

                String itemName = item.getItemName();
                String itemPrice = item.getItemPrice();
                viewHolder.setItemName(itemName);
                viewHolder.setItemPrice(itemPrice);
                viewHolder.setItemAddBtn(itemName, itemPrice, comm);

            }
        };

        mItemsList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    public static class ItemsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View mView;

        public ItemsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView = itemView;
        }

        public void setItemName(String name) {
            TextView mUser_name_view = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.item_display_single_name);
            mUser_name_view.setText(name);

        }

        public void setItemPrice(String price) {
            TextView mItem_price_view = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.item_display_single_price);
            mItem_price_view.setText(price);

        }

        public void setImage(String image, Context context) {
            CircleImageView mItem_image_view = (CircleImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.item_display_single_image);

            Picasso.with(context).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_profilepic).into(mItem_image_view);

        }

        public void setItemAddBtn(final String itemName, final String itemPrice, final Communicator comm) {
            Button btn = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.item_display_single_add_btn);

            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    comm.sendToBill(itemName, itemPrice);
                    Log.d("ItemPrice", "item price adapter " + itemPrice);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of your fragments here, and they are not added to the activity:

```
@Override
public void sendToBill(String itemName, String itemPrice) {
    count++;
    FooterBillFragment footerBillFragment = new FooterBillFragment();

    BillFragment billFragment = new BillFragment();
    billFragment.updateBill(itemName, itemPrice);

    Log.d("ItemPrice", "item price inter " + itemPrice);
    footerBillFragment.updateFooterAmount(itemPrice);
}
```

That's why you receive a NullPointer, because the method `onActivityCreated` will never be called in your `FooterBillFragment`

Comment: So do i have to create them in the IntermediateActivity oncreate and the use the refferences in sendToBill?

Comment: Exactly. You can read the documentation here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Thanks a lot!! it's working. How can i give you +100

Comment: It is working you can accept the answer. I'm glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

```
onActivityCreated()
```

Created in Activity and your fragment's view is null because your fragment is not create .Use TextView's method in `onCreateView()`.

Comment: Already solved it but thanks for your comment. I apriciate it!